# Rails POST json Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been at this for the past day or so in my Rails 3.2.11 app in Ruby 1.9.3, having read every SO post close to this that I can. The below seems closer to getting this record to be written because I've fine tuned the action because of the SO responses. I have a commodity and I want to write a Price record that is tied to the commodity. To learn how to create a basic API, I wrote a namespace and a separate Price controller.

After attempting to use the build action that I use in the controller for the html, I bailed on that approach and just added the commodity_id in the JSON call since I'm expecting the user to have the commodity_id in the url. My updated Api::PriceController#create is just a basic create to the Price model.

Commodity.rb

```
 class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :name
   has_many :prices
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
 end
```

price.rb

```
 class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :buyer, :date, :price, :quality, :commodity_id
   belongs_to :commodity
 end
```

prices_controller.rb

```
 class PricesController < ApplicationController
   def create
   @commodity = Commodity.find(params[:commodity_id])
   @price = @commodity.prices.build(params[:price])
 end
```

api/prices_controller.rb

```
 module Api
class PricesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    def create
      respond_with Price.create(params[:price])
    end
    end
   end
```

routes.rb

```
 namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
   resources :commodities, only: [:show, :new, :create] do
    resources :prices
   end
 end
```

Here is my curl call:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3004//api/commodities/1/prices.json -d "{\"price\":{\"prices_attributes\":[{\"price\":8,\"buyer\":\"Sam\",\"quality\":\"Bad\",\"commodity_id\":1}]}}"
```

The response to this is "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: prices_attributes"

OK, I believe I should be able to do this because another SO post says that so long as I don't include the created_by, updated_by timestamps I should be good. But I'm not. In another SO post a similar poster to me got his to work to make the JSON call like an AREL call and wrap it in a prices_attributes. Yanking this wrapper so that it looks like this:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3004//api/commodities/1/prices.json -d "{\"price\":{\"price\":8,\"buyer\":\"Sam\",\"quality\":\"Bad\",\"commodity_id\":1}}"
```

returns a "undefined method `price_url' for Api::PricesController". Why does this seem to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Price doesn't have nested prices and there is no `accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices` in the Price model, Commodity has. The JSON is bad in that you're trying to save prices nested attributes within price model. In the first example your JSON should look like this:

```
... "{\"commodity\":{\"prices_attributes\":[{\"price\":8,\"buyer\":\"Sam\",\"quality\":\"Bad\",\"commodity_id\":1}]}
```

Notice "commodity" instead of "price" in the JSON. Second JSON is entirely wrong.

Read through [API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for better understanding of nested attributes in Rails.

Comment: This is the revised rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: This gets me almost to the next step. For some reason, it doesn't like any form of the "8" as it fails my validation for price. But I'll get it figured out. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

Nested attributes allow you to append forms for other models within a form. So in your case you were attempting to nest price forms within a commodity form. If that is what you intended, then in your commodity class you need to append `:prices_attributes` as `attr_accessible`

```
class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :prices_attributes
    has_many :prices
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
end
```